# Error: cuDNN isn't found FWD algo for convolution

Tags: python, prediction, yolo, cudnn

I try to training Yolo v3 with the following cfg

```
[net]
# Testing
#batch=1
#subdivisions=1
# Training
batch=64
subdivisions=16
width=608
height=608
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 4000
policy=steps
steps=3200,3600
scales=.1,.1
```

But When I try to increase subdivisions ,It does not recognize the object inside the image, knowing that I trained on 2000 iteration

increase subdivisions ,It does not recognize the object inside the image, knowing that I trained on 2000 iteration

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.